# What keeps happening to my desktop icons?

Tags: linux-mint, icons, cinnamon

I'm using Linux Mint 13 Cinnamon for an HTPC.  When it originally boots, the desktop icons look like this:

[image]

After I come back to it some time later, the desktop icons have changed and they look like this:

[image]

Does anyone know why this is happening?  Is something crashing?

I realize I'm being kind of vague, which is why I made sure to provide screenshots on this one.

Comment: Don't know, but my guess is something along the lines of `gnome-settings-daemon` is getting started up later, and changing your theme.  Not sure how to exactly track it down other than to be careful and pay attention to what triggers it.